# JQuery remove multiple <p> in contenteditable div using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am trying to make a remove multiple

using jquery regex for my contenteditable div. But i have one problem here. So i have try it like in this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/VbjqPV)**.

In this demo if you press enter then my js code doesn't allow to create paragraph but i just want to remove if user create tree times empty paragraph.

I don't want to allow :

```
    Hi



    Bro



    How are you




   thanks
```

I want to do it like this :

```
Hi

Bro 

How are you
thanks
```

So here is my codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("keyup", ".text", function() {
      var item = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0];
var text = item.innerText || item.textContent;
      // var text = $(".text").text();
    
   text = text.replace(/<[\/]{0,1}(p)[^><]*>/gi, ' ');
   document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].innerHTML = text;
   });

});
```

```css
.text {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:500px;
   margin:0px auto;
   padding:30px;
   border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
   margin-top:50px;
   border-radius:3px;
   -webkit-border-radius:3px;
   -moz-border-radius:3px;
}
.text[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before  {
      content:attr(placeholder);
      color: #444;
    }
* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Write something with tree times enter"></div>
```

Comment: why the dots after "how are you" have no space?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That is nothing. I just tell with `....` user can continue to write a word with another multiple `<p></p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p:empty + p:empty + p:empty { display: none; }
```

...would do the job, if your `<p>`s were actually empty. However, it looks like they are not (they contain `<br />`s).

So, a probably better option would be to use a function that turns the text into html, checks for occurrences of 3 empty paragraphs, removing the third:

```js
function removeThirdParagraph() {
  let clone = $('.text').clone();
  clone.html($('.text')[0].innerHTML);
  let ps = clone.find('p');
  
  ps.each(function(i,e){
    if ($(e).is('p + p + p') 
    && isEmptyP(ps.eq(i - 2)) 
    && isEmptyP(ps.eq(i - 1))
    && isEmptyP(ps.eq(i))) {
      e.remove();
    }
  });
  // you probably want $('.text').text(clone[0].innerHTML)
  $('.text').html(clone[0].innerHTML)
}
function isEmptyP(p){
  return p.text().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\s)/g, '').length == 0;
}
removeThirdParagraph();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <p>
    <br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <br />
  </p>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    <br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </p>
  <p>another test</p>
  <p>
    <br />
  </p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have still try it but the developer console looks like this: [SCREENSHOT](https://scontent-otp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/18057200_452184608448037_1567284725616726290_n.jpg?oh=97433f1a322950a6dec3f6899f1811f8&oe=597BB8FF) . That means this solution is not working for me.

Comment: Those `<p>`s are far from empty. They each have a `<br>` tag inside them. I'll think of another way, but please note your question is not accurate.

Comment: Yes those `<p>`s are far from empty. it is why `p:empty {display: none;}` doesn't work.

Comment: @DevStud. Updated my answer with a function that seems to do what you need.

Comment: @andrei-gheorgiu Yes it is working good. But it is not possible to use it with when user typing in contenteditable div ?

Comment: Place it inside a function bearing a name and you can call that function from anywhere you want. function `removeEmptyPs(){ /*...code here */}`

Comment: Do you mean i can do it like this ? [DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/BRLzQV) It didn't worked.

Comment: It can't work. Your `<p>` is plain text, not a DOM element. To make it work you would need to make it proper markup first, using .html(contents). But that's going to break whenever your markup is not valid. What you're trying to do is not so simple. You have to check if it's valid markup, turn it into markup when it is and check if it has anything in it. Consider studying how dedicated libraries do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer dear. So i have a little question. Is it possible to allow one empty line `<p></p>` with your answer ? If yes how ? I think regex can do it for us>

Comment: @DevStud, I apologize. I didn't notice you want to remove every third paragraph. I thought you want to remove all empty paragraphs. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @DevStud: updated. It now removes third "empty" paragraph.